File path for image, HTML, VS Code

I'm new to html and coding, trying to understand file paths.
When my workspace in VS Code is Folder_1, I code this in page_1.html:
<img src="Fiddlepic.jpg"/> 

and all goes well, photo shows in Preview.
So to test out my 'path' skills, I change workspace to Folder_2, and try this in page_2.html
<img src="../Folder_1/Fiddlepic.jpg"/>  

and the photo doesn't show up in Preview now.
I thought the .. would take me from Folder_2 back up to main_folder, and then /Folder_1/Fiddlepic.jpg would get me to the right place. VS Code was predicting this path as I typed as well...and I can control-click on the element and it takes me to the photo.
I have screen shots but I'm not sure if that's the done thing on here.

"I change workspace to Folder_2" - When you test this, is VS Code running a development web server to serve the files?  What is the URL of the page being viewed in the browser when testing?

You mean when I click "open with Live server"?
This is the URL:  http://127.0.0.1:5500/page_2.html

The clue is in a comment above:

This is the URL: 127.0.0.1:5500/page_2.html

The src value here is not a file system path:
<img src="../Folder_1/Fiddlepic.jpg"/>

It's a URL.  The browser (client) doesn't know or care anything about the file system (server).  It's just making URL requests to a web server.  In this relative URL, it's going "up one folder" and then "down one folder into Folder_1".  However, what does "up one folder" mean for this page?:
/page_2.html

It means nothing.  The URL is already at the root of the web server.  So when the web server receives this request:
/Folder_1/Fiddlepic.jpg

And when the root folder of the web server translates server-side into this:
/Documents/Folder_2/

Then the resulting request is for:
/Documents/Folder_2/Folder_1/Fiddlepic.jpg

Which doesn't exist.

You'll either need to put the file within the web server directory so a URL can exist which serves that file, or make the workspace (and thus the root of the web server) one more folder up on the file system (in this case Documents) so all of the files are served by that one web server.

Ok, thanks for your help. I'm not sure I understand totally but I'm only new so I'm sure it'll make sense in time.

I get it now, thanks. It was late last night here in Australia and my head wasn't working right!
So using the file structure I have on my original post now (I had 2 conflicting diagrams last night, sorry) , I could open main_folder in VS Code as my workspace and my paths work fine.
Thanks again for your help.
